# How to prevent WordPress from auto creating ol li on list elements?

Tags: blog

At first some informations:

WordPress Version: 4.9.5

Theme: Twenty Fifteen Version: 1.9

Plugin: Crayon Syntax Highlighter (only)

I use a Childtheme to be updateable.

---

I want to write a Blogpost, where I have Listelements. It should look like this:

```
1. header

  some text
  picture
  codesample

2. header2

  and so on...
```

But it looks like that:

```
1. header

  some text
  picture
  codesample

  2. header2

  and so on...
```

The Sourcecode builds a `ol li wrap` around the 1., but the 2. is just a `2.`

I want to prevent WordPress from creating automatic ol li, because if I add the 2. Number it becomes an indent before the 2.

Don't looks good, because the indent is different.

How can I prevent WordPress from creating just the ol li's OR

how can I use the ol li's with the correct value and indent?

Important: I don't want to write the Sourecode by myself. I could, but I don't want to use the Backend-Blog-Formular with own Code. Just using WordPress like i have to. ;)

Comment: Use `tab` and `shift + tab` to indent and 'outdent' list items into higher or lower levels.

Comment: Normaly its a good idea, but i can't remove a indent of a non list-element. I can't start with 2. and I can't make something between 1. and 2. so I think undo ol li is the best way, because I can't write a `1.` without getting a list element.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Answer:

- I press the Listbutton and get a `1.`.
- I write my Text behind `1.`.
- I **press shift AND enter**.

Now I can add everything I want between 1. and 2. without loosing the List-Indent.

Important is the `shift` key while pressing `enter` to get to the next line without the next Number.

- If I want the next Number I press simply the `enter` button.

This works for Text, Image and Codeblocks from Crayon Syntax Highlighter Plugin.